# How to share folders between win11(host) and Debian(guest)

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I am trying to share folder between win11(host) and Debian(guest) so I follow these steps:

1- Go to Virtual `Box/Device/Shared` Folder (on host OS)

2- Add a folder that you want to share in the pop-up. (on host OS)
Let’s name this folder “Shared” (on host OS)

3- Now Go to Device and install guest addition.

4- Now next step would be to create a folder that you want to sync with host OS, but make sure that you are at `/home/UserName`.

You can check it by typing pwd in the terminal. Now creating directory -

```
mkdir Share
```

5- Now install guest additional package (Crucial step! People generally miss this which creates an error “Unknown file type “vboxsf”)

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
```

6- Now do the final step by mounting the folder (on guest OS)

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf share ~/Share/
```

In Step 6 I got on

```
mount: home/debian/share/: mount(2) system call failed: No such file or directory.
```

But when use `pwd` I got on `/home/debian`

How can fix the error please?

Comment: 1. `~/Share/` != `home/debian/share/` 2. Does this work `sudo mount -t vboxsf share /home/your_user_name/Share/`?

Comment: Also check this: https://serverfault.com/questions/674974/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder

Comment: I used sudo mount -t vboxsf share /home/your_user_name/Share/  and I got on the same error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the beginners like me, I solved this error by:

1- cd .. /..

2- sudo mount -t vboxsf share /home/your_user_name/Share/

3- Enjoy in your shareable files between the host and guest!

Comment: *"I used sudo mount -t vboxsf share /home/your_user_name/Share/ and I got on the same error !"* vs this answer. Sorry, I don't follow. That's also a nice "Thank you" but that's not the first time I get thanked this way.