# How to share folders between Debian (host) Win11 (guest)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have the reverse of this situation -
[How to share folders between win11(host) and Debian(guest)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747819/how-to-share-folders-between-win11host-and-debianguest)

Debian Buster, Windows 11, Virtualbox 7

Without the Windows 11 VM booted up, I clicked

**Settings > Shared Folders > Machine Folders > Add Share**

Then select the folder on the Linux host that I want to share with the mouse.

Then I click "auto mount" and under Mount Point write :

```
C:\Users\vboxuser\Desktop\SharedFolder
```

..but when I boot up the VM into Windows 11, the shared folder is not there.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or forgetting?

Comment: Did you install the [Virtualbox guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-install) to enable sharing with Windows?  According to the [documentation regarding shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders), you would not set a mount point for Windows guests and the volume will be available through file explorer (provided by guest additions).

Comment: Thanks @GracefulRestart that did it, it's accessible now. Removed the mount point for Windows Guest. Actually every time I "inserted" Guest additions with the device menu, nothing happened and I had about 3 instances of drives. So I ejected all of them and then re-inserted once when it prompted me to _install_ Guest Additions and that was it. It needs to be installed not just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

As resolved from the comments, make sure that the [Virtualbox Guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-install) are correctly installed in the guest.

Also, the [configuration of Virtualbox shared folders on windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders) does not require a mount point, as it is handled by the guest additions and should be available in the file explorer.